# How to assign words to values in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list with 4 different numbers, 10 numbers in total. To each of those numbers, I want to assign a color/word.
The question is thus, how do I go from a list of numbers to a list of colors where every same number is represented by the same color/word?

**Initial list:**

```
my_list = [72, 50, 3, 50, 16, 72, 3, 72, 3, 50]
```

**Expected output:**

```
print(my_list) -> ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
```

What did I try?

I extracted unique numbers from my_list:

```
my_list = [72,50,3,50,72,3,72,3,50]

UniqueList = list(set(my_list))
print(UniqueList)
```

Now I need to assign a color from a list of colors ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'yellow', 'purple'] to each of those 4 unique numbers and then generate my_list again with colors. Unfortunately I have no clue how to go forward. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a lookup dictionary:

```
my_list = [72, 50, 3, 50, 16, 72, 3, 72, 3, 50]
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'yellow', 'purple']

lookup = dict(zip(set(my_list), colors))
output = [lookup[number] for number in my_list]
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
['red', 'green', 'black', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'red', 'black', 'green']
```

You can consider the `lookup` dictionary as a function that assigns a color to one of the number. In the example above lookup has the following value:

```
{72: 'red', 16: 'blue', 50: 'green', 3: 'black'}
```

This means that it will assign `'red'` each time `72` appears. You can customize `lookup` like this:

```
lookup = {72 : 'green', 50 : 'black', 3 : 'yellow', 16: 'purple'}
```

This time each time `72` appears `green` will be assigned. See more on how to create dictionaries in [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

**Update**

If you want to preserve the order of appearance in the list you could to the following:

```
seen = set()
result = []
for e in my_list:
    if e not in seen:
        result.append(e)
        seen.add(e)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[72, 50, 3, 16]
```

Notice that the list `result` is in order of appearance.

Comment: Omg, this is perfect! Just what I was looking for. ;-)

Comment: One more question. Now, in this example, the look-up selects the first four colors and randomly maps them with the four unique numbers and applies that color-guide for the other numbers. How can you make sure the first unique element in the list of numbers is mapped with the first element from the list of colors? (without manually setting the dictionary like you showed in the last example; suppose the values itself are unknown in the beginning). So that when you run the code, you always get the same output, now the order in which it picks unique colors is variable.

Comment: You could filter the list in order using a set

Comment: Well let's say in this list the first unique number is the first one, then the second, third and then the fifth is the last unique number. Is is possible to map them fixed with the elements from the colors-list. first unique number with first color; second unique number with second color etc. in that order? It's just a question, if it's too complex that's ok, but it would make the output fixed (instead of variable as it is now) ;-)

Comment: Do you mean: lookup = dict(zip(set(my_list), set(colors))) ? so adding set to colors?

Comment: No, see unique_everseen function, https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200906/discussion-between-daniel-mesejo-and-matthi9000).

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide a dict of {int: color} key value pairs and then do the following:

```
my_list = [72, 50, 3, 50, 16, 72, 3, 72, 3, 50]
mymap = {72: 'red', 50:'blue', 3:'green', 16:'black'}

print([mymap[k]for k in my_list])

## output
['red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
```

Comment: Aha! Indeed that works too but hmm what if the values that will appear in the list are unknown until I extract them from a function? I know how many different values there will be but not what they are because the function chooses them at random.